# Two JVMs and setting the environment variable having issues

Tags: jvm, java-home

I am working on two projects one uses JDK 8 and other uses JDK 6. 
I installed both the jdks in my machine where JDK8 is set as my default JVM. so I am good with one project settings.

When I am working on second project, I tried to change JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 and PATH added with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin and surprisingly I am seeing JDK8 as my default JVM. I checked with java -version or java -fullversion.

Questions.

Where should I stop the Java process that is initiated with JDK8 ?
Where should I start the Java process for JDK6 ?
How should I easily switch JVMs when I switch back and forth working on two projects ?

I dont like the idea of uninstalling one jvm when I have to work with another jvm.

Please suggest me. Thanks for your time.

Narayana.V

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program in your shell, it is the `PATH` environment variable which determines which program is run.  This is a feature of DOS prompt and unix shells and not specific to Java.  If you want to change the program which is run by default, you need to change the PATH.

Comment: Sorry.. I didnt mention that.. My path refers to JDK1.6 but still it picks up JDK8.

Comment: @NarayanaVakkalagadda On windows there is a java.exe in the System32 directory. You need to put your preferred version before this in the path.